# gnu sed remove portion of line after pattern match with special characters

Tags: sed, special-characters

The goal is to use sed to return only the url from each line of FF extension Mining Blocker which uses this format for its regex lines:

```
{"baseurl":"*://002.0x1f4b0.com/*", "suburl":"*://*/002.0x1f4b0.com/*"},
{"baseurl":"*://003.0x1f4b0.com/*", "suburl":"*://*/003.0x1f4b0.com/*"},
```

the result should be:

```
002.0x1f4b0.com
003.0x1f4b0.com
```

One way would be to keep everything after `suburl":"*://*/` then remove each occurrence of `/*"},`

I found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24140/return-only-the-portion-of-a-line-after-a-matching-pattern but the special characters are a problem.

this won't work:

```
sed -n -e s@^.*suburl":"*://*/@@g hosts
```

Would someone please show me how to mark the 2 asterisks in the string so they are seen by regex as literal characters, not wildcards?

edit:

```
sed -n 's#.*://\*/\([^/]\+\)/.*#\1#p' hosts
```

doesn't work, unfortunately.

regarding character substitution, thanks for directing me to the references.

I reduced the searched-for string to //*/ and used ASCII character codes like this:

```
sed -n -e s@^.*\d047\d047\d042\d047@@g hosts
```

Unfortunately, that didn't output any changes to the lines.

My assumptions are:

`^.*something` specifies everything up to and including the last occurrence of "something" in a line

`sed -n -e s@search@@g` deletes (replace with nothing) "search" within a line

So, this line:

sed -n -e s@^.*\d047\d047\d042\d047@@g hosts

Should output everything after `//*/` in each line...except it doesn't.

What is incorrect with that line?

Regarding deleting everything including and after the first / AFTER that first operation, yes, that's wanted too.

Comment: Have a look at the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Escapes - you have to escape the special characters, `\*`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's#.*://\*/\([^/]\+\)/.*#\1#p' file
```

Match greedily (the longest string that matches) all characters up to `://*/`, followed by a group of characters (which will be referred to as `\1`) that do not match a `/`, followed by the rest of the line and replace it by the group `\1`.

N.B. the sed substitution delimiters are arbitrary, in this case chosen to be `#` so as make pattern matching `/` easier. Also the character `*` on the left hand side of the substitution command may be interpreted as a meta character that means zero or more of the previous character/group and so is quoted `\*` so that it does not mistakenly exert this property. Finally, using the option `-n` toggles off the usual printing of every thing in the pattern space after all the sed commands have been executed. The `p` flag on the substitution command, prints the pattern space following a successful substitution, therefore only URL's will appear in the output or nothing.